# Eclipse (C++) and eigen

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, eigen

I have eclipse set up to point at my eigen main include directory, and it knows about the basic matrix and vector types, but complains about other things such as .norm(), .dot(), and ::Zero(x,x).  The code compiles fine.  Any idea how I can get eclipse to be happy?  I have another instance of eclipse in a similar arrangement that works fine, but have been unable to find any differences in settings.

Comment: It would help to provide a concrete (and preferably minimal) code example.

Comment: And also state what versions of Eigen and Eclipse you're using.

Comment: I'm on a system isolated from the internet, so I can't just paste something in, but it's pretty simple.  If I type "Eigen::MatrixXd M = Eigen::MatrixXd::Zero(2,2)", the Zero() will be underlined and "cannot be resolved", likewise for ".norm()" or ".dot()" applied to any vector.  I'm using Eigen 3.2.4 and Eclipse Luna.  Thanks.

Comment: "Eclipse Luna" --> there's your problem. That's a 4-year-old version, and its C++ parser has a lot of deficiencies. I'm not at all surprised that it can't handle code like Eigen that's heavy on template metaprogramming. If you try the latest version of Eclipse, I'll bet it handles it a lot better.